# Why am I getting empty array?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I was doing CS0 problem set 7 - CS50 Finance where they use flask and SQLite.

When I try to access stock_name="s" on phpliteadmin i get the corresponding row, however when I try to access via code I get empty array [] while it should be outputting [{key:value,etc...}], see the line commented #HERE.

What is the problem with it? How can I access my database.

```
@app.route("/sell", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def sell():
"""Sell shares of stock."""

if request.method=="POST":
    if not request.form.get("symbol"):
        return apology("Symbol name cant be empty")
    elif request.form.get("symbol"):
        rows=db.execute('SELECT * FROM portfolios WHERE username=:username AND stock_name=:stock_name',username=session["user_id"],stock_name="s")
        print(rows)#**HERE**
        if rows==[]:
            return apology("No such stock name")
    elif not request.form.get("shares"):
        return apology("Shares missing")
    elif request.form.get("shares"):
        try:
            number_shares=int(float(request.form.get("shares")))
        except:
            return apology("Invalid shares")
    elif rows[0]["shares"]<request.form.get("shares"):
        return apology("Sorry not enough shares")
rows=db.execute('SELECT * FROM portfolios WHERE username=:username AND stock_name=:stock_name',username="u",stock_name="s")
print(rows)                
return render_template("sell.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found out that it was related to string concatenation in python, therefore I use + sign concatenation like:
 **"SELECT * FROM portfolios WHERE username="+usernameValue+"\""